# Evaluation Copy of InstallShield and Version Control

Tags: version-control, installshield

My employer currently has access to a singular InstallShield 2016 Professional key. They're looking at upgrading to 2018 Premier and getting a second license, but want me to test out 2018 Premier by working with our actual installer. All of our installer files are checked into version control with the rest of our project.

According to Flexera's documentation, an evaluation copy of InstallShield implements a time limit for running setups produced by it. Makes sense - they don't want you creating your installer in the 21 day limit and then never buying the product.

If I'm careful not to implement anything specific to 2018 or Premier, will checking in anything I create and having it re-built on the machine with the full license avoid triggering this restriction? There are concerns that using the evaluation copy of 2018 Premier in an actual working environment will ruin what's already checked into version control and implement a five-day limit for our installer.

**Note:** We do plan on using the evaluation copy only as an evaluation. The trial period will be to determine how much more efficient it is to have two devs working on the installer, as well as to figure out if upgrading to Premier is worth the cost. We may or may not end up purchasing a second license at the end of the trial.

Comment: This is not so much a programming question rather than one about the behaviour of some other, closed-source software under certain circumstances. Contact the vendor with your support request.

Answer (score 0):

The expiration is built based on either the project requesting it, or the use of an evaluation copy of InstallShield for the build. So merely opening and saving the project with an evaluation copy will not mark a project as an evaluation. Nor will making and saving changes.

However, opening and saving a project in a newer version of InstallShield will upgrade the project, rendering it unusable (and thus unbuildable) in the older version of InstallShield. The Professional and Premier editions of the same version are generally compatible, but opening a project in the Professional edition may disable various features that were enabled in the Premier edition, even if you don't attempt to alter them.

Source control should make it easy to undo any project changes that interfere with your builds.